# Hardlink/Softlink won't work with my.cnf on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm using `MariaDB 10.3.14` and i wan't to store the `my.cnf` on another directory.

I had try to create following cenarios:

- Hardlink (named as `my.cnf`) to `/opt/config/myqsl/my.cnf`
- Softlink (named as `my.cnf`) to `/opt/config/myqsl/my.cnf`
- `!include /opt/config/myqsl/my.cnf` with overritten options/settings
- `!includedir/opt/config/myqsl` with overritten options/settings

As sample, the new configuration has either the overritten option/settings of `bind-address` (expected it's an linked file or an include)...

But when i try to change the value of `bind-address` (with value `0.0.0.0` for a global connection or `127.0.0.1` for only local connections), the settings are not adopted.

How i can change the path of the `my.cnf`?

Comment: Okay, i've found the solution: The config file must be had permissions of `rw-r--r--` 
(`0644`)

Comment: Being owned by `mysql` (or `mariadb`?) is another approach.

Comment: Its only an permission problem.